# urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error unknown url type: https

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

I am developing a Python App for the Assetto Corsa racing simulator game. The game comes with a Python (3.3) DLL package which is used to run these third party apps, which has caused some trouble for me.

I am trying to make a request to fetch some data with this code:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://github.com")
```

This code works fine for any `http` url but gives the following error for any `https` url:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

After doing some digging, I figured that the packaged Python DLL isn't built properly with SSL which is causing this problem.

Taking a look at the compressed python33 folder, I do see a file `ssl.py` along with the rest of the python standard libraries but I guess this python instance hasn't been configured with ssl.

Most of the fixes I've read have to do with upgrading your python version, reinstalling python altogether, or installing an SSL package. None of these work for me though as I don't have control of the python environment, and can't really install packages unless I download the source code. Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?